# What does “with that” mean here?

Tags: grammar, idioms

I heard this sentence from a news program:

“Anytime we release people into the United States pending a hearing with that they’re not gonna show up to, we’re gonna have tons of people across our borders illegally.”

Does “with that” in this sentence mean “after”?

Can “a hearing with that they’re not gonna show up to” also be said this way - “a hearing they’re not gonna show up to with that” or “a hearing they’re not gonna show up to after”?

Comment: This is hard to parse as the transcription may not be the best. And "with that" can just be a speech error, too. Or,  "with that" can be the legal mechanism used for releasing them. Where did you obtain this transcription? He's attempting to say they are released pending a hearing and often will not show up.

Comment: This is the original version:  “*Any time we release people into the United States pending a hearing that they’re [illegal immigrants] not going to show up to, we’re going to have tons of people cross our borders illegally*," Judd told "Fox News Live" on Sunday.

Comment: So now we now there was *one word* out of place: **With**.